# .pip folder not in HOME directory on OSX

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm trying to edit ~/.pip/pip.conf file but the .pip folder is not present in osx.

I have pip installed globally as well as using it in various virtual environments.

Do I need to create this folder and file manually?

Comment: It is not present for me on ubuntu either, it would be in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf` on mac for per user or `/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf` for system wide if it existed

Comment: I looked in both places, no .pip folder

Comment: You should be able to just create it

Comment: should I create it in HOME folder or in `$HOME/Library/Application Support

Comment: According to the docs I don't think it matters, the paths are searched in a certain order but all paths are searched, you can set an environment variable to use a custom path `PIP_CONFIG_FILE`

Comment: I don't see it written anywhere that it would be harmful. Confused why it doesn't exist on my mac either.  Pip website on configs for more reference: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

Comment: Not sure, it is not something I ever needed to use although from memory in older version of pip I do seem to remember it was in my .pip folder in my home directory

Answer (score 2):

To add to this as I was looking to set this up globally because the latest pip error was bothering me

```
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. 
You can use --format=(legacy|columns) 
(or define a format=(legacy|columns) 
in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
```

I ended up creating a .pip directory with a pip.conf file under my $HOME directory for global usage:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir .pip
cd .pip
touch pip.conf
```

Hope this helps anyone trying to figure out where their global pip is looking for a config file on OSX

Answer (score 1):

It should be in `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create my own pip.conf file.

If using virtual env, create the pip.conf at the root of `$VIRTUAL_ENV` or the root of your virtual env folder.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the .pip folder will be hidden as well as the new empty file pip.conf.
To view this folder from the Apple Finder, open Terminal, at the prompt$ copy/paste this in:
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true

Next, copy/paste this in:
killall Finder

You can now see the hidden folder, then you can open the pip.conf file from an application like Pycharm, enter in your index-url information, save, and then use pip install .
To reverse the visibility of Hidden Folder/Files go to the prompt$ and enter:
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false

Next, enter this in:
killall Finder

Result: The Apple Finder will restart and hide all the 'hidden' folders/files.